# Any example of measurable spaces where the measurable rectangles form an algebra on the product space?

Tags: measure-theory, products, borel-sets, measurable-sets

As far as I know, for any $(\Omega_{i},\sigma_{i})$ i=1,2, $\textit{A}=\{A_{1}\times A_{2}: A_{1}\in\sigma_{1}, A_{2}\in\sigma_{2}\} $ is not an algebra in general on $\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}$ in general because it is not closed for finite unions nor complementaries. I'm trying to think about an example of particular spaces where this is true, but the only one that appears to work is choosing the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma_{i}=\{\emptyset,\Omega_{i}\}$ for one of the spaces. Any other idea on how to proof A is an algebra in other spaces, because when I try with $\sigma$-álgebra with more than one set different from the empty one, I don't find a way to write the union of measurable rectangles as a measurable rectangle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no example where there exist sets $A$ and $B$ in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively which are non-empty and also not equal to the whole space. Suppose $(A \times B)^{c} =C\times D$ for some $C$ and $D$. Then $C=\Omega_1$ and $D=\Omega_2$ : for any $x \in \Omega_1$ we can pick $y \notin B$ to see that $(x,y) \in  (A \times B)^{c} =C\times D$ and this implies $x \in C$. Similarly $D=\Omega_2$. But now if we pick $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ we get $(x,y) \in C \times D$ but $(x,y) \notin (A \times B)^{c}$ a contradiction.

Comment: Yes your argument is basically what made me think that what i was looking for doesn't exist but don't you think that, as I said, it is only necessary for one of the sigma-algebras, because with just one of them being the trivial sigma algebra you can't pick the 'y' you mention, and in the case of just one of them being trivial it is easy to proof the measurable rectangles are an algebra (in fact, a sigma-algebra).

Comment: @heyou Yes, what you are saying is right.